# Order of Django Data Migrations

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I am using the sites application (`django.contrib.sites`) in my application. I have created a data migration which sets the values of the current site when the database is created, however my data migration is being executed before the sites application is installed. How can I force my data migrations to be executed after the `sites` migrations.

This project is intended to be a seed to be used for other projects, and I often delete the database and start fresh so it is important that the initial makemigrations/migrate commands work out of the box.

My migrations file exists in the main application folder:

```
project folder
..+app
....+migrations
......-0001_initial.py
```

Here is the content of the migration file:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations

def set_development_site(apps, schema_editor):
    Site = apps.get_model('sites', 'Site')
    current= Site.objects.get_current()
    current.domain = "localhost:8000"
    current.name = "Django-Angular-Webpack-Starter"
    current.save()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(set_development_site),
    ]
```

And the output from the `python manage.py migrate` command:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, app, auth, authentication, authtoken, contenttypes, sessions, sites
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying authentication.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying app.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/devel/django-angular-webpack-starter/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 149, in get_app_config
    return self.app_configs[app_label]
KeyError: 'sites'
```

Comment: python manage.py sites. And after launch your command for your app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sites framework is not enabled (migrated) by default. This is why you can't reference `Site` model before Sites' migrations. You have to [enable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework) and migrate it first. You want to do: `manage.py migrate sites` and `manage.py migrate`.

#### Update

If you want to use only `manage.py migrate` try adding `sites` as a dependency to your migration file:

```
dependencies = [
    ('sites', '0001_initial'),
    ...
]
```

Relevant doc article [here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/#accessing-models-from-other-apps)

Comment: Ok that works, though I would really like a way to force the sites app to migrate before accessing the model so my end users can just run `python manage.py migrate` like normal - and everything just works - when starting a new application from my library.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Ok, the updated solution works - with one minor change for me: the site doesn't exist after the sites migrations run, you simply need to create the site with `current= Site.objects.create(domain=...',name=...)` instead of `current= Site.objects.get_current()`.